# How do you dynamically rename a node in a ASP.NET sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sitemap

On our site, we have our sitemap in this order:
SiteName > SelectedProject > Path > To > Page
Where SiteName takes you to the very root page which is primarily to select a project and SelectedProject takes you to the project's homepage.

Currently, in the Web.sitemap file, SelectedProject has a static name. How can I rename it to the name of the selected project, which can be obtained from Session("PRJ")?

I'd strongly prefer any code behind to be given in VB.NET, not C#. Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first is you site map coming from the database or is it fully static???

if you want it to make it dynamic you have to make a new table and store all your data there!!

but if that file is static then i think you can use this code:

```
theNameOfYourSitemapControl.selectedNode.Text ="thenameoftheproject"
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like the solution I needed.